# constant tableviewcell at the beginning of the tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I would like to know if there is any sneaky way of getting a `UITableViewCell` to appear at the beginning of a `UITableView` no matter what the array that is going to populate the tableview contains?

I am having issues where I would like to have a "select all" cell at the top of the tableview but currently having issues trying to adjust the arrays I have going into the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of your end goal, but there are many ways some easier (sneaky ways) than others depending on your needs.  It sounds like your items are fairly static, so you can just insert them before you display or update the table row.

say you have a datasource called self.items and you did something to get data.  Maybe in your app you are round tripping to some data source based upon input, like sort selectors or from the search bar delegate.

try something like this in the area where you load your datasource.

```
NSString *myCustomObject = @"Jump To Songs";
self.items = [self getGetMovieList];
[self.items insertObject:myCustomObject atIndex:0];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Another easy way would be to add sections to your table  and just make the first section your navigation items.

Note: you may need to handle the actions in didSelectRowAtIndexPath......

there you go, not so sneaky, but pretty simple.
be well

Comment: okay cool.. this sounds alot like what I am trying to do at the moment, the main issue being is that I recive the data, send it to a sorting method and then send the sorted data off to the tableview method.. So i need to inject at some point between finishing sorting (because I Want it at the first entry of the array) and before i display it.. Is the best way to insert an object into an mutable/array using the `insertObject:atIndex:` method?

Comment: there are many ways to manipulate arrays but insertObject: atIndex: is pretty commonly used, especially if you need to locate it at a certain position. but it does need to be mutable.

Comment: yea I thought that.. got abit confused when i started getting errors thinking that it was not increading everything in the array by 1 position, what it was however was the section count being blown out. Will let you know how i go then mark u correct if it ends up working right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make two types of `UITableViewCell`, then return the "select all" one if `indexPath.row == 0`.

On the other hand, how about just make a `UIView` for the "select all" functionality, and set it as the `tableHeaderView` of your table view?